# Laravel grouping or taking from list in six

Tags: php, laravel

I'm not sure the title of this topic is correct, I apologize, you suppose I have this list which I get them from the database:

```
menu-index
menu-create
menu-store
menu-edit
menu-update
menu-destroy
commonCategory-index
commonCategory-create
commonCategory-store
commonCategory-edit
commonCategory-update
commonCategory-destroy
usersRole-index
usersRole-create
usersRole-store
usersRole-edit
usersRole-update
usersRole-destroy
```

as you can see we can grouping them with the first part of each item that we can have that them in three groups, after grouping them I want to use `foreach` for each one item that's there. I try to use the `Laravel` collection, but I can't. Could you help me please how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```php
Model::all()
    ->groupBy(function($item) {
        // Might want to add some checks here, but that depends on your setup
        return explode('-', $item->getAttribute('columnName'))[0];
    })
    ->each(function($item) {
        // do sth.
    });
```

But it might be more performant to add a `group` column to your model already.